# Ruby on Rails: It is recommended to only use MongoDB database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to Ruby on Rails 3.2.x, I've done a couple of projects and so far everything has worked fine, but for my new project I decided to use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) with [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) gem (because its great scalability, performance and ability to handle large volumes of data)

I've been reading documentation and blogs about MongoDB and Mongoid the last 4 days, I've done a few demos and it really is a beautiful thing. But despite everything, I have seen some people who say:

*"Not only use MongoDB in your application, use it in conjunction with a SQL database as an additional database for large data volumes and little relation of models."*

Is that correct today?

I see MongoDB and Mongoid growing quickly because according to wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), MongoDB was released in 2010 and I don't know if most of the problems you could have, are resolved yet. For example: [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) works fine with MongoDB!

You've had some experience using just MongoDB as database engine recently?

What would you think be your biggest problem using only MongoDB? Gems, hosting prices, backups, or some SQL feature that you could ever long for?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There are some discussions on this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933852/mongodb-or-mysql-or-both-in-a-rails-app



http://ryanangilly.com/post/1091884265/3-reasons-to-use-mongodb

Comment: Thanks for your comment Muntasim, but i notice something: According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), MongoDB was released in 2010 and these items are 2 or 3 years ago. My question is: Is now MongoDB reliable for use in production as the only database.

Comment: the answer below has some points regarding this

Comment: Your question would be a better fit on a discussion forum than here. Also check here: http://www.10gen.com/customers

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're building. There are situations where sql schema fits you perfectly.

A good usage experience with pros and cons is given here [a year with mongodb](http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/20988881092/a-year-with-mongodb) and a good example of using both is [here](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/How-NoSQL-MySQL-and-MogoDB-worked-together-to-solve-a-big-data-problem)